# How do I open a directory in text mate via terminal

Tags: directory, terminal, textmate

I am following a tutorial for ruby on rails and in the video the guy opens the directory we are currently inside in terminal as a textmate project. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `mate` terminal command, see how to use it here:

http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html

HTH

Comment: Im sorry but I am not sure what the command would be based off of this link. I already created the symbolic link when i first setup text mate. I just need to know how to open this whole folder in text mate.

Answer (score 8):

When you are in a directory in terminal, to open all files in TextMate, use

```
 mate .
```

If you want to open a single file, use

```
 mate <the file name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the textmate 2, it comes with this command line utility. What you need to do is turn it on.

Go to "Preferences", and then "Terminal" to turn on.

See http://blog.macromates.com/2011/mate-and-rmate/